# Symfony2, Error "The uploaded file was too large." without file field

Tags: symfony

So i have unknown error when start use 2.3 version of symfony
Assert Entity

```
class FormRegister
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Regex
     * (
     *      pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/i",
     *      message="You use illegal character(s). Must be a-z, A-Z and 0-9 symbols."
     * )
     * @Assert\Length
     * (
     *      min="4",
     *      minMessage="User name must be more then 3 characters.",
     *      max="15",
     *      maxMessage="User name must be less then 16 characters."
     * )
     */
    private $username;

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * (
     *      message="Password is required. :)"
     * )
     * @Assert\Length
     * (
     *      min="4",
     *      minMessage="Password must be more then 3 characters.",
     *      max="25",
     *      maxMessage="Password must be less then 255 characters."
     * )
     */
    private $password;

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * (
     *      message="Email is required."
     * )
     * @Assert\Email
     * (
     *      message="Email address has incorrect type, try re-type or use another mail."
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    /**
     * @Assert\True
     * (
     *      message="We can't register if you will not accept our terms."
     * )
     */
    private $terms;

    public function setTerms($terms)
    {
        $this->terms = $terms;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTerms()
    {
        return $this->terms;
    }
}
```

FormType

```
class FormRegisterType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'User Name :'))
                ->add('password', 'repeated',
                        array(
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'first_name' => 'pass1',
                    'second_name' => 'pass2',
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password:',),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm Password:'),
                    'error_bubbling' => true,
                    'invalid_message' => 'Password not matched.'))
                ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'E-Mail'))
                ->add('terms', 'checkbox', array('attr' => array('class' => 'checkBoxTerms')));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Main\SiteBundle\Form\FormRegister',
            'required' => false));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'FormRegisterType';
    }
}
```

Action

```
 public function registerAction()
    {
        $formRegister = $this->createForm(new FormRegisterType(), new FormRegister());

        if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $formRegister->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
            $formData = $formRegister->getData();

            if ($formRegister->get('username')->isValid())
            {
                $exist = $em->getRepository('MainSiteBundle:User')
                        ->findOneByUsername($formData->getUserName());

                if ($exist)
                {
                    $error = new FormError('Such account name as "'.$formData->getUserName().'" already exists');
                    $formRegister->get('username')->addError($error);
                }
            }

            if ($formRegister->isValid())
            {
                echo 'form is valid';
                $ef = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $user = new User();
                $pass = $ef->getEncoder($user)->encodePassword($formData->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());

                $user->setPassword($pass)
                        ->setUsername($formData->getUsername())
                        ->setEmail($formData->getEmail);

                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
            }
            else
            {
                var_dump($formRegister->getErrors());
            }
        }

        $twig = 'MainSiteBundle:Default:register.html.twig';
        $data = array(
            'formRegister' => $formRegister->createView());

        return $this->render($twig, $data);
    }
```

If input valid data i still will have error on 'file type' which i didn't use!

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[1418]
      private 'message' => string 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.' (length=69)
      protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.' (length=69)
      protected 'messageParameters' => 
        array (size=1)
          '{{ max }}' => string '2048M' (length=5)
      protected 'messagePluralization' => null
```

Where is the problem? I didn't sending file at all. It appears in 2.3 version i start to use.

```
var_dump($formRegister->getErrorsAsString());
```

Give me such

```
string 'ERROR: The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.
username:
    No errors
password:
    first:
        No errors
    second:
        No errors
email:
    No errors
terms:
    No errors
' (length=212)
```

**UPDATED**

Template

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ path ('site_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(formRegister)}}>

    {{ form_errors(formRegister.username) }}
    {{ form_label(formRegister.username) }}
    {{ form_widget(formRegister.username) }}
    <br />
    {{ form_errors(formRegister.password.first) }}
    {{ form_label(formRegister.password.first) }}
    {{ form_widget(formRegister.password.first) }}
    <br />
    {{ form_errors(formRegister.password.second) }}
    {{ form_label(formRegister.password.second) }}
    {{ form_widget(formRegister.password.second) }}
    <br />
    {{ form_errors(formRegister.email) }}
    {{ form_label(formRegister.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(formRegister.email) }}
    <br />
    {{ form_errors(formRegister.terms) }}
    <div class="terms">
        {{ form_widget(formRegister.terms) }} I read <a href="#">this terms</a> and accept.
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Comment: How and where did you dump the form's file error ?! please provide this information

Comment: look in controller action I posted

Comment: is the error message shown when you submit the form and render the tample? how does the template look?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

at symfony.com 2.3 version changed to BETA, will roll back to 2.2 stable, troubles because it's not tested and is BETA

Comment: In June 3rd, Symfony 2.3 was released as stable version. You can read more here: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-3-0-the-first-lts-is-now-available

Comment: three days ago it was with BETA tag ;) look at github - a lots of bugs on 2.3, so i will wait a little bit $;)

Comment: For all who read this, look at date! Don't down-vote this one, at that time it was bugged (means beta).

Answer (score 14):

You should increase **both values** in php.ini

```
 post_max_size = 50M    
 upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

you can see your php.ini configuration:

```
 php -i | grep "your text to find"
```

I hope to help you

Comment: Nice. It was the `post_max_size` that wasn't set to the correct size. Didn't know I had to set/sync both values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to upload a file in some point that is too large. Do you use some other form in that action?

You can read in the Symfony 2.3 documentation: [File validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#uploadinisizeerrormessage)

> ***uploadIniSizeErrorMessage***
>
> **type**: `string` **default**: `The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is {{ limit }}`
>
> The message that is displayed if the uploaded file is larger than the upload_max_filesize PHP.ini setting.

Comment: he states he is not uploading a file and as you can see his form doesn't contain a file field-type. i guess he does already understand what the error says ;-) Anyways the hint to php.ini `upload_max_fileisze` is good for others facing the exception possibly.

Comment: Yes, I saw he is not sending a file. However, in some other point may have another form with and upload field. I updated my answer to ask him that.

Comment: of course not, you think I will hide "main part of code with file rules declaration and then ask about file error" ? no rules for file, simple register form (as in manual) and no, one form - one action this is all code

Answer (score 1):

In your **Entity.php** you need to specify the "[maxSize](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize)" property to your [Assert file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).

The unit of this value is bytes.

"2147483648" for 2GB.

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
public $path;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="2147483648")
 */
public $file;
```

Answer (score -2):

Was a bug on Symfony2.3

Fixed there: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/9048